# How do I add a warning with Groovy AST transformations?

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I see on the `SourceUnit` object that I can `addError(SyntaxException)`, but how do I add a warning?

EDIT: Anyone know how I can either get a `CSTNode` in the `CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS`, or how I can simply add a warning with only having to know the line number and column number (just like the `addError` function works)?

EDIT 2: I tried just creating a `CSTNode` myself, but it didn't seem to work as eclipse didn't show the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Can you call `getErrorCollector()` on `SourceUnit` then add the warnings to that with one of the `addWarning(...)` methods?

Comment: Do you know how I can get a `CSTNode` for passing into the `addWarning` method?  I only know how to get `ASTNode` s.

Comment: @Kyle There's a `getCST()` method in `SourceUnit`. Does that not help?

Comment: Returns null. I suspect that it would return something other than null if `CompilePhase.PARSING` was set, but that can only be set in Global AST Transformations rather than local AST Transformations.

Comment: This was asked almost 9 years ago did anyone ever figure this out? I can call addWarning , but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I ran into this problem too (2021) and I can't figure it out eiter... anybody?